# Is there a iPod touch 1st gen recall program by Apple?

Tags: ipod-touch, applecare

I have a iPod touch 1st generation and was about to sell but somebody said to me to get in touch with Apple because apparently they are recalling them and I could get a iPod touch 5th gen? Is this right, and if so how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no exchange or repair for the 1st Gen iPod touch. Perhaps someone confused the exchange from the 1st gen *nano* with the *touch*

You can find a full list of Apple exchange and extended service plans here:

- https://www.apple.com/support/exchange_repair/

A recall means specific things in the US and most other countries and you would see formal advertisements, probably a note on Apple's home page www.apple.com as well as receive email and/or direct postal mail if a product was recalled. The iPod touch hasn't been recalled in the normal sense of that word.

Comment: @bmike Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but the question is talking about the first gen iPod touch and you are discussing the iPod nano?

Comment: I'm very confused as I was about to sell my iPod touch first generation and a friend told me they are recalling and replacing with a newer version I'm not talking about the iPod nano
thanks

Comment: @jodie and George You're both right - my edit made this worse. I'll fix it now. My apologies.

Comment: @bmike No problem, I got a hat!

Comment: @grgarside Mullet or hairboat? I'm now jealous and wondering who I need to piss off to get a down vote somewhere. :-)

Comment: @bmike Mullet, haha :)